# How To Place Cheat Engine Game Pointer In a C++ program

Tags: c++

I have a C++ program hack for a game (that kind of like Minecraft) that gives me more items, and it works perfectly fine. But What's annoying is that whenever I close the program and start it again, the value changes. I got past that part with **static Values** but I realized that you can't put them in a C++ program. Heres what the code looks like. (just to let you know this isn't gonna work unless you have the game downloaded)

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;
// Important Pointers-----------------



DWORD item = 0x23CE113C;   // <- this part will change every time game is closed
//------------------------
DWORD processID;

int hackeditem;

int main() {
    std::cout << "Looking For Selected Game";
    Sleep(1000);
    system("cls");
    HWND hwnd = FindWindow(0, ("Block Story")); //This searches for Window
    if (hwnd) {
        cout << "Found Selected Game!" << endl;
        system("pause");
        system("cls");
        int item;
        cout << "What Item Do You Want To Hack?" << endl;
        cout << "1. Wood" << endl;
        cin >> item;
        if (item == 1) {
            system("cls");
            cout << "Enter The Amount Of The Item You Want: " << flush;
            cin >> hackeditem;
            cout << "Press Enter When Ready To Hack" << endl;
            system("pause");
            system("cls");
        }
        else {
            cout << "Selected Game Not Found :(" << endl;
            Sleep(1000);
            cout << "Hint, Try opening Selected Game First, Then This" << endl;
            system("pause");
            return 0;
        }
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &processID);
        HANDLE pHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, processID);

        WriteProcessMemory(pHandle, (LPVOID)item, &hackeditem, sizeof(hackeditem), 0);
        // Code above this gets game memory, and code above edits it
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and here's what the pointer looks like:
[image]

But if I put that pointer in there (p->2310905C) it's gonna give me an error saying ***identifier "p" is undefined*** and ***Expected a member name ***

Is there anyway around that so if i put it in a C++ program and download it on someelses computer, i don't have to constantly change the values

Comment: Hard to help you without a minimal, verifiable, example.

Comment: What info do you want, I can explain quite a lot

Comment: “just to let you know this isn’t gonna work unless you have the game downloaded.” Please take time to take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and repost your question with a [minimal, verifiable, example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can actually help you out.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to help you without much information. Is the 'program' you close the cheating program or the game? I'd say save and close the game with the program running, then close the program.

Answer (score 0):

In an external trainer, if you want to walk a multi level pointer which you have recorded with Cheat Engine you can use the popular FindDMAAddy() function.  It will de-reference each pointer and add the offsets for you and return the final address pointed to by the pointer chain.  Then you can use WriteProcessMemory to write to the resulting address

```cpp
uintptr_t FindDMAAddy(HANDLE hProc, uintptr_t ptr, std::vector<unsigned int> offsets)
{
    uintptr_t addr = ptr;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < offsets.size(); ++i)
    {
        ReadProcessMemory(hProc, (BYTE*)addr, &addr, sizeof(addr), 0);
        addr += offsets[i];
    }
    return addr;
}

//example
uintptr_t ammoAddr = FindDMAAddy(hProcess, dynamicPtrBaseAddr, { 0x374, 0x14, 0x0 });
```